# Python subprocess is not working as expected for find command

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am trying to find out orphan files on the node in python. 
Below is the code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
try:
        s = subprocess.check_output(["find", "/", "-fstype", "proc", "-prune", "-o", "\( -nouser -o -nogroup \)", "-print"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output
else:
    if len(s) > 0:
        print ("List of Orphan Files are \n%s\n" % s)
    else:
        print ("Orphan Files does not Exists on the NE")
```

When I try to run this python code

```
> python test.py 
find: paths must precede expression: \( -nouser -o -nogroup \)
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

When I run the same command on CLI it is working fine.

```
> find / -fstype proc -prune -o \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print
/root/a
```

Few of you suggested to use shell=true, as per the python doc for subprocess it is security hazard.
**`Warning Using shell=True can be a security hazard.`**

Answer (score 2):

Just add shell=True to your check_output

```
s = subprocess.check_output(["find", "/", "-fstype", "proc", "-prune", "-o", "\( -nouser -o -nogroup \)", "-print"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should split the command on every whitespace. The easiest way to do this is with [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd = shlex.split('find / -fstype proc -prune -o \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print')
subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `shell=True` option and then just pass the entire shell command. I think the whitespace is causing the issue.

```py
s = subprocess.check_output("find / -fstype proc -prune -o \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print", shell=True)
```

Note [this warning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) relating to setting `shell=True`. Basically don't do it if the input comes from an external source (like user input). In this case it should therefore be fine.

Comment: could you please help me understand, how it can be fine?

Comment: @sach Your shell command is hard coded. Something like `command = raw_input("Enter a shell command > ")` then `subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)` might be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your script and got the same error as you did. I was trying different things and found something that worked for me. I changed

```
-print
```

to

```
-exec
```

and it worked. But I am not sure why this was the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Each command line parameter must be passed as a separate list item, including the parentheses and their contents:

```
s = subprocess.check_output(["find", "/", "-fstype", "proc", "-prune", "-o",
                            "(", "-nouser", "-o", "-nogroup", ")", 
                            "-print"])
```